# Selenium : How to enter text in div inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

HTML code:

```
<div class="listRte__editorFrame">   
     <iframe src="about:blank" style="height: 150px;">
           #document
                <html>
                   <head>
                       <body>
                            <button class="__clipped">
                                  <div data-ghosttext="Add a detailed description here." contenteditable="true">
                                   ::after
                                  </div>
                             </button>
                        </body>
                    </head>
              </html>
        </iframe>
 </div>
```

I want to type a text in the div.
Html after adding the text manually :

```
<div contenteditable="true">abcd</div>
```

I tried to enter text using javascript:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("document.evaluate('//div[@data-ghosttext=\"Add a detailed description here.\"]', document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML="+ "\"abc\"");
```

**But it gives me error:**

> org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: TypeError:
>   document.evaluate(...).singleNodeValue is null

---

I also tried switching to iframes, but not able to recognize the div when switched to iframe. Also, I get `size=0` when I try following command. However there are 3 iframes on the page when I inspect element.

```
 int size = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
```

---

Can I please get the exact command in Java/js using which I can type something in the div element.
I work on selenium using testng framework

Comment: Is your question solved or you are still looking for an Answer?

Comment: It resolved. All I had to do was to switch the iFrame first and then pass text in div element as usual. No JavaScript was needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch to the appropiate `frame` first then try to pass any text within the `div` as follows:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='listRte__editorFrame']//following::iframe[1]")));
```

Answer (score 1):

> But it gives me error: org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException:
>   ReferenceError: abcd is not defined

`abcd` needs to be quotes as well

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.evaluate('//html//body//div', document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML="+ "'abcd'");
```

or *escaped double quotes*

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.evaluate('//html//body//div', document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML="+ "\"abcd\"");
```

Or simply

```
jse.executeScript("document.querySelector( 'div' ).innerHTML = " + "'abcd'" );
```

Comment: Thanks. But after adding quotes, I am getting a new error: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.

Comment: So, it is not able to identify the element, maybe your `xpath` is wrong. You haven't shared the relevant markup here. Anyways the problem you had originally asked has been solved.

Comment: hey Thanks ! I was getting error on the next line. I deleted that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158373/discussion-between-vj-qe-and-gurvinder372).

Answer (score 0):

To get list try:

```
List<WebElement> listFrames = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
System.out.println("list frames   "+listFrames.size());
```

Next 
Switch to frame

```
driver.switchTo().frame(listFrames.get( frameIndex ));
```

and after that try to input that text.